# IBM Nested Relational Database White Paper

Tags: database, nested

I'm reading up on recent advances in databases and came across many references to a White paper by IBM entitled "Nested Relational Database". However the links seem to be broken, and I have not been able to find a copy on IBM's website.

Does anyone know where I can find a copy of this paper?

Comment: Please post the broken link (Although broken)

Comment: One is: ftp://ftp.software.ibm.com/software/data/u2/pubs/whitepapers/nested_rdbms.pdf

Comment: Another is: http://www-3.ibm.com/software/data/u2/pubs/whitepapers/nested_rdbms.pdf

Answer (score 1):

You most likely *won't* find it on IBM's website, the UniVerse product that it relates to has been onsold to Rocket Software (I think IBM have a relationship with Rocket on quite a few products).

Rocket's whitepapers are [here](http://www.rocketsoftware.com/u2/pubs/whitepapers.html) but I'm not sure if any of those are the specific ones you're after.

For what it's worth, a search of IBM's internal sites also turns up very little on "Nested Relational Database" but that's not really that surprising gieven how seriously IBM takes intellectual property. They almost certainly would have handed over everything and scrubbed all records. Your best bet would be to [contact Rocket Software](http://www.rocketsoftware.com/about/contact) and ask them if they have it available.

Answer (score 0):

Seems that IBM sold the whole business division to Rocket.
You may find the site here http://www.rocketsoftware.com/u2/